# css: correct way to put a div element right next to another div (at the bottom) if they are not together

Tags: css

Let's say we have something like:

```
<div id="1" class="A"> </div>
<div id="2" class="B"> </div>
<div id="3" class="C"> </div>
```

**How could we put the div with id 3 right next to the div with id 1?**

I tried to do it with negative margins:

```
.C{
    margin-top:-45px;
}
```

It usually looks good:

[image: margin negative good luck]

But sometimes, if I resize the font with the internet browser, it looks bad:

[image: margin negative bad luck]

**UPDATE1**: real code showed by the browser with the idea of @Zhihao implemented (unfortunately not working).

html:

```
    (...)

    <div class="pull-right socket-div">
        <p class="logout"> usuario: 
            <a href="/webAlojamientoUCA/logout/index"> 
                <button class="btn btn-small btn-info" type="button">
                        Salir
                </button>
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>      
</div>
    <div class="container">         
        <div class="row-fluid">                         
            <div class="span12">    
                <div class="plug-div">  
                    <div>
                        <div id="mini-carousel-photos" class="carousel slide centrar-imagen capa-inferior">
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="item">  

                                    (...)
```

css:

```
.socket-div {
    display: block; 
}

.plug-div {
    display: block;

    height:0px;
    float: center;
    /*  position: absolute; */
    /* position: fixed;  */

    margin-top:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
    border-top:0px;
}
```

Browser screenshot:

[image: DISPLAY BLOCK BAD LUCK]

Comment: Can you set fixed heights on the top bar navigation? Then you can adjust it down by whatever height you set, and font size won't affect it. Also, if it's positioned absolutely, use `top: 45px` instead.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "right down to"? Also, what are you giving negative margins?

Comment: what do you mean by _right down_?

Comment: @aug, with right down, I wanted to say right next, at the bottom. What is the correct way to say it in English?

Comment: @zhihao, I'm using negative margins because if not, there is a blank space between the navigation menu and the image (because there is a div with information between)

Comment: @matthewpavkov, I'm using Twitter Bootstrap. It mixes relative and absolute, margins...

Comment: I edited the question. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Assuming `#2` and `#3` both have `display: block`, you would typically do this by giving `#2` a height of 0 or removing it from the flow of the page with `position: absolute`, `position: fixed`, or `float: left`. If neither of these options would work for you, it sounds like you should restructure your HTML.

Comment: Another quick-fix might be to change them so that font size will not affect how much space they take up. For example, you could explicitly set the height (and then center the text vertically).

Comment: Could you try to reproduce what you're trying to do in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).  It's hard to figure out what the photos are doing and which div corresponds to which.

Comment: I agree with KyleMit. Can you tell us what each div corresponds to in the picture example you gave us?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion of setting a height on the main nav bar? Can you provide a live code example?

Comment: @matthewpavkov, I don't understand what you mean with _setting a height on the main nav bar_. The navbar is not at the top: there are logos and blank spaces (margins and stuff of twitter bootstrap).

Comment: I didn't posted my code because it is already too big. Actually, the divs are in different gsp (grails) pages. I thought it would be confuse and useless for the rest of the people to post it. Tomorrow I'll try your first quick-fix @Zhihao (with `display:block`). I think it will work.

Comment: @KyleMit, I updated my question with the generated html of the browswer as it is actually more readable than my code itself.

Comment: @Zhihao, the updated question has the result of your (first) idea. I'm not sure what you mean with your second one (I think it is the same that mattewpavkov said. There are more stuff before the navigation bar, like logos).

Comment: Thanks for the update. To start with, `float: center` does not exist - it must be `left`, `right`, `none`, or `inherit`. Also, is `.plug-div` the div2 in your example? From what's shown, I still feel `float: right` should work unless something else is floated there. Are you also sure div2 is pushing div3 down (you can check with the browser developer tools)? With height 0, it should not take up vertical space. Whatever is pushing div3 down, we need to make sure that portion's height does not change with font size change.

Comment: It began to work @Zhihao! I understood you better with your last comment :) I was setting height = 0 to div3. But **we must to set `height = 0 `to div2**. Actually, I removed the rest of css (`display: block` and `position: absolute`), and it keeps working. The small issue now is that all the text (of other pages) moved up. I guess the solution is to create a `margin-top = 30px;` for these pages. Feel free to answer my question (or I'll do it myself if you prefer)  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the comments:

The issue is that `div#2` is between `div#1` and `div#3` and takes up space, which means `#1` and `#3` cannot be adjacent. The solution is to make `#2` not take up any space.

This can be done by setting the `height` of `#2` to 0. Otherwise, we can take `#2` out of the flow of the page using `position: fixed` or `position: absolute`. Setting `float` to `left` or `right` may also work if neither `#1` nor `#3` are floated.